# Splitting an observableList using toString

Tags: java, javafx

So I am trying to split an observableList using toString:

```
listeMedLag = DataHandler.hentDataCupLag("src/arrangementer.csv",2,listeMedLag,cup); //output: Skjeberg&Borgen
listeMedLag.toString().split("&");
lagSomErMed.setItems(listeMedLag); //output: Skjeberg&Borgen
```

Anybody know why the list ain't splitting?

Comment: Use `lagSomErMed.setItems(listeMedLag.toString().split("&"));`. `listeMedLag.toString().split("&");` returns a different array of strings which you are not assigning to anything.

Answer (score 3):

```
listeMedLag.toString()
```

Creates a string based on the elements of the list. There are multiple problems with that. The `ObservableList` implementation may not create exactly the string output you expect. Also usually there are `{}` wrapping the content.

Also invoking methods on objects returned by methods of an object usually won't have an effect on the original object. There are exceptions, but they are documented. (Examples would be `List.subList` and `List.iterator`). `String` is immutable though and it has no connection to the list whatsoever. Calling `split` on the string simply results in an new `String[]` array being created that contains parts of the string. It has no effect on the string object and also no effect on the list.

If your intention is to split every element of a `List<String>` and fill a list with all those elements I recommend you create a new list containg all those elements and then assign the contents to the target list:

```
List<String> inputList = ...
ObservableList<String> outputList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

// fill new list with elements of original list split at "&"
inputList.stream().map(s -> s.split("&")).forEach(outputList::addAll);

// do something with new list
listView.setItems(outputList);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to store that splitted string into a local variable. like:

```
String[] split =  = listeMedLag.toString().split("&");
lagSomErMed.setItems(split);
```

or

```
lagSomErMed.setItems(listeMedLag.toString().split("&"));
```

`split` method signature:

```
public String[] split(String regex)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `flatMap` to transform a list into a list with a different number of items.

```
        list.setAll(list.stream()
            .flatMap(item -> Arrays.asList(item.split("&")).stream())
            .collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

This will set the contents of `list` to new items, so if you have an listeners they will probably be fired a lot.